# Page not found after click in Django

Tags: python, django, menu

I have a simple menu-list

```
{% block menu %} 
    <ul>
    {% for item in list %}
    <li><a href="{{item}}/">{{ item }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

and a list:

```
MENU = ['Home','Contact','About']
```

When I press Contact then go to the address `127.0.0.1:8000/Contact`
with this same template but if I again click Contact I'm getting Page not found at `127.0.0.1:8000/Contact/Contact`

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The particular issue here is that the HTML you emit has links to "Contact/", which if you're already at a /Contact URL, will go to a /Contact/Contact like you see here.

The quick fix is to add a / right before the {{item}}, like this:

```
<li><a href="/{{item}}/">{{ item }}</a></li>
```

However, django has better ways to handle URLs than creating them yourself.  Look at the URL dispatcher documentation [1], with the intention of being able to use the url template tag [2].

What that line would end up looking like then is something like this:

```
<li><a href="{% url item %}">{{ item }}</a></li>
```

1. [1] http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/
2. [2] http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `href="{{item}}"` to `href="/{{item}}"`:

```
(% block menu %} 
    <ul>
    {% for item in list %}
    <li><a href="/{{item}}/">{{ item }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

You were using a relative URL which won't work if you're in a different level of the URL path.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths, for example:

```
MENU = [{'text':'Home',
    'url':'/home'},
    {'text':'Contact',
    'url':'/contact'},
    {'text':'Home',
    'url':'/home'}]
```

And code like this:

```
{% block menu %} 
    <ul>
    {% for item in list %}
    <li><a href="{{url}}/">{{ text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

But better solution would be to use some ready CMS app, for example from here [django resources page](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources#Djangoapplicationcomponents) like django-cms ( django-cms.org ).